# How to disable code completion in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

How to disable following window appearing:

[image]

Disabling all checkboxes in `Preferences -> Java -> Editos -> Content Assist -> Advanced` didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Preferences -> Java -> Editors -> Content Assist -> Auto Activation`

You were close.